# Lambda Calculus Extended/Revised substitution rule

Tags: lambda-calculus

Wikipedia's [Lambda Calculus article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Substitution) defines the substitution, $M[x:=N]$ by recursion as follows:

1. $x[x:=N] = N$
2. $y[x:=N] = y$, if $x \not =y$
3. $(M_1M_2)[x:=N]=(M_1[x:=N])(M_2[x:=N])$
4. $(\lambda x.M)[x:=N] = \lambda x.M$
5. $(\lambda y.M)[x:=N] = \lambda y.(M[x:=N])$, if $x \not =y$ and $y \not \in FV(N)$

where $FV(N)$ is the set of free variables of $N$.

Can `5.` be extended/revised to account for cases where $y \in FV(N)$ as follows:

5. $(\lambda y.M)[x:=N] = \lambda y.(M[x:=N])$, if $x \not =y$ and ($y \not \in FV(N)$ or $x \not \in FV(M)$)

   - If $y \in FV(N)$, then $(\lambda y.M)$ must be $\alpha$-renamed to use "$\lambda z$" instead of "$\lambda y$" for some variable $z \not \in FV(N)$. After the renaming, `5.` can be applied.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, that is what the text immediately after the definition in the Wikipedia page is telling you. As a tiny optimisation, there is a special case when $y \in FV(N)$ but $x \not\in FV(M)$.

Comment: @RobArthan gotcha. I wanted to get it in exact notation. Updated the revised `5.` to include the optimisation.

Comment: Your notation looks good to me.

Comment: Reviewing brilliant.org's article on Lambda Calculus, I see they have a similar set of rules for substitution:

https://brilliant.org/wiki/lambda-calculus/#:~:text=The%20capture%2Davoiding,defined%20as%20follows%3A